# Скрытие бокового адаптивного меню при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Когда посетитель открыл боковое меню и скролит вниз оно плавно закрывается(боковое меню) Как написать такой скрипт? Буду благодарен:)

Comment: При onscroll делайте отсроченное исчезновение меню через setTimeout()

Comment: я не знаю как сам скрипт написать просто Js еще не хорошо знаю. Но спасибо Вам)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (pos > lastScroll) $('nav').fadeOut();
  lastScroll = pos;
});
```